# Connecting to Java server with open localhost does not work

Tags: java, sockets, telnet

When I use MS telnet, I'm getting every character repeated WITHOUT CRLF but with OSX telnet, my input is not sent to server until I CRLF.

So I found I can first open (MS) telnet and type

```
set crlf
```

but then when I try to open the connection, the client sits there and says it's Connecting but then fails!

What's the difference between these commands below and how can I connect by using **open** command?

Commands:

Working:

```
telnet localhost 8010 // but I get unwanted auto-send
```

Not working:

```
telnet
set crlf

open localhost 8010
```

Code:

```
   public class SingleThreadedBlockingServerBasic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(8010);


        while (true) {

            // Connect client and serverSock - Tell serverSock to accept client Socket
            Socket client = serverSock.accept();

            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();

            int data;

            // Read the int-read into the 8k buffer at offset 0 from the inputstream. inputstream receives data off
            // of the client Socket.
            in.transferTo(out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably a difference in how the telnet clients work.

Comment: @K.Nicholas They're the same client ...

Comment: "MS telnet, I'm getting every character repeated WITHOUT CRLF but with OSX telnet,"  -> MS telnet is not OSX telnet.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Right, with OSX it is different. So what I'm saying is that when I try to set crlf with Windows telnet...I then can't connect. So the question is why can't I use open with MS telnet? I'm not asking about OSX

Comment: Most likely MS telnet is not the right tool for your needs.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'm testing Java sockets so its part of a course but the instructor is gone from Q&A. I think this is a common way to learn about sockets or test certain environments or applications. I guess...

Comment: You could save a lot of headache by using [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) rather than (MS) telnet.

Comment: @Armali Oh wow you're right....... thanks for telling me!